# How to handle image resize in media_handle_sideload?

Tags: uploads

I am using `media_handle_sideload` function to upload images in my plugin. Is it possible to disable image resize or set it to a specific size and do not make copies (upload only resized image).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`media_handle_sideload`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L269) in source, you can see how it works.

The function that generates the various sizes is within [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata), the [`image_make_intermediate_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_make_intermediate_size) function.

You could possibly use the `wp_handle_sideload` function instead and manually resize it via [`image_make_intermediate_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_make_intermediate_size).

Comment: can you provide some examples on it?